# Show, $U_\alpha:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{K}^3\mid x+y+z=\alpha\}$ with $a\in \mathbb{K}$ is subspace of $\mathbb{K}^3$ over $\mathbb{K}$ if $\alpha = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Show, that $U_\alpha:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{K}^3\mid x+y+z=\alpha\}$ with $a\in \mathbb{K}$ is a subspace of the vector-space $\mathbb{K}^3$ over $\mathbb{K}$ if $\alpha = 0$

First we need to show that $U_\alpha \neq \emptyset$.

Let $y=(\alpha,0,0)\in U_\alpha \implies U_\alpha\neq \emptyset$

---

2.) $\forall u,v\in U_\alpha:u+v\in U_\alpha$

Let $u = (a,b,c)$ and $v=(d,e,f)$ with $a+b+c=\color{red}{\alpha} \in \mathbb{K}$ and $d+f+e=\color{red}{\alpha} \in \mathbb{K}$

$$u+v =(a+d,b+e,c+f)$$
with $\color{red}{a+d+b+e+c+f = a+b+c+d+e+f = \alpha+\alpha=2\alpha}$  and this implies, that $u+v\notin U_\alpha$, except for $\color{red}{\alpha} =0 \implies \color{red}{0+0=0}$ (Is this detailed enough?)

---

3.) $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{K},\;\forall u\in U_\alpha:\lambda u \in U_\alpha$

$$\lambda u = (\lambda a,\lambda b, \lambda c)$$

with $\lambda(a+b+c)=\lambda \alpha \neq \alpha$ except for $\alpha = 0$.

$U_\alpha$ is a subspace only for $\alpha = 0$

Comment: You should take $a+b+c= \alpha$ and $d+f+e= \alpha$ (as you assume $u,v \in U_\alpha$) and then $2\alpha = \alpha$ if $\alpha =0$. Also, don't write $u+v= \beta + \gamma$, this is not true.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I thought it would be a different number but that would be wrong. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I've fixed the wrong statements/assumptions.

Comment: Is it good now?

Comment: Not quite. First $u,v \in \mathbb{K}^3$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$, thus you cannot write $u+v= \alpha + \alpha$. Second, $2\alpha = 0$ does not imply $\alpha=0$ (unless you secretly assume that $char(\mathbb{K}) \neq 2$). I suggest that you have a look at mechanodroid's beautiful answer, then everything will become clear.

Comment: Alright, ^^ ${}$

Comment: I still changed it, this should fix the problems you pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to first argue that necessarily $\alpha = 0$ because otherwise $0 \notin U_\alpha$ and every subspace has to contain $0$.

Now for $U_0$ we can easily check that it is a subspace:

- $0 \in U_0$ so $U_0 \ne \emptyset$
- For $u,v \in U_0$ we have $$(u_1+v_1) + (u_2 + v_2) + (u_3+v_3) = (u_1+u_2+u_3) + (v_1+v_2+v_3) = 0$$
  so $u+v \in U_0$
- For $u \in U_0$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ we have
  $$\lambda u_1 + \lambda u_2 + \lambda u_3 = \lambda(u_1+u_2+u_3) = 0$$
  so $\lambda u \in U_0$

Comment: Thank you, that would indeed make things a bit easier!